# expression: stream.valid() error on c code

Tags: c, windows, runtime-error, visual-studio-2022, txt

i tried creating a simple program to read files from a txt file and tried to open a txt file and read some numbers from it but for some reason i get [this error msg](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/490523870579916813/1113916406724046891/wutisthat.png) which for some reason every fix i found is completely different from the other suggestions and it doesnt work.
anyone know whats the problem?
this is a part of the code which even alone does the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const double g = 9.81;

int main() {
    FILE* Result = NULL;
    double m[5], l[5];
    char line[100];
    fopen_s(&Result, "Result.txt", "rt");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), Result)) 
    {
        if (line[0] == '\n') { 
            continue;
        }
        sscanf_s(line, "m:%lf l:%lf", &m, &l);
        printf_s("m:%lf l:%lf\n", m, l); 
    }

    fclose(Result);


    return 0;
}
```

i tried searching for the words in the error msg online but i cant find any fix that helps me get rid of it

Comment: You need to check that `fopen_s()` is successful.

Comment: fopen_s() is a microsoft extension so you should tag is as such.

Comment: Why do you have these arrays: `m[5], l[5]`? You can't `scanf()` or `printf()` an array, like you appear to be doing.

Comment: do i have to check fopen? i assumed its just to check if the file exist, since i only started writing it i didnt add anything about it. 

and about the arrays, what other way is there to write the m/l values of the txt file into the code? using a variable for each one is impossible since im suppose to make it a dynamic array in the future of the code

Comment: Before you try to store multiple sets of values in arrays, please enable more warnings in your compiler so that it tells you that your code is broken. Maybe it already is and you're ignoring it. What compiler are you using? What OS are you using? You should edit your question to contain important information like this.

Comment: im using visual studio 22 and windows 10, im a real newbie in programming so i usually just do parts of codes and run them alone to see if there broken or not so i dont bother adding any error messages or failssafes since this is the most basic way i know of making it so even if i tried to i would have no idea how it can go wrong or where

Comment: at `sscanf_s(line, "m:%lf l:%lf", &m, &l);` you are passing pointer to pointer at m and l vars while you should pass just pointer, and opposite problem is at `printf_s("m:%lf l:%lf\n", m, l);` where m and l are pointers while they should not be

Comment: Try to get the error code by:
`errno_t error_code;`
`error_code = fopen_s(&Result, "Result.txt", "rt");`
and let us know the value of `error_code `